# NGINX Not sending cookie on web application logout

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on, session-cookies, httpcookie

I am using NGINX's `auth_request` directive for SSO as well as reverse proxies, and everything works well, other than logging out. The log-out functionality doesn't work, i.e. I do get redirected to the login page, but the client-side cookie is still set.

When logging out directly via the application directly (i.e. through the application port directly) without going through the NGINX reverse proxy, the following HTTP header is sent:

```
set-cookie: next-auth.session-token=; Max-Age=0; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

However, when I logout through NGINX itself, this HTTP header is not sent.

Here is my NGINX config for the auth flow:

```
server {
        location / {
                auth_request /auth; 
                auth_request_set $new_cookie $sent_http_set_cookie;
                add_header Set-Cookie $new_cookie;
                ...
                # Successful login, redirect to application
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8100;
        }

        location /auth {
                internal;
                proxy_pass https://sso.sol/api/auth/check;
                proxy_pass_request_body off;
                proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }
        error_page 401 = @error401;

        # If the user is not logged in, redirect them to SSO auth
        location @error401 {
                return 302 https:/sso.sol/auth/sign-in/?redirectURL=https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```